# Reajustar tamaño de texto con el borde de un formulario

Tags: php, bootstrap

Cordial saludo equipo, necesito pedirles el favor con el siguiente inconveniente, en la siguiente imagen se subraya el área que se desea  eliminar de un área de trabajo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se necesita es eliminar el área detallada de color rojo en la imagen debido a que para el cliente el tamaño entre el texto y el borde del Div sobra

Discúlpenme que publique código tan extenso, pero es que necesitamos de manera urgente este requerimiento:

```
   <span style="font-size: 14px;">
<?php echo $row["DescripCurso"] ?> 
</span>
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!------------------ -->
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4"> 
<div class="single-service margin-bottom">
<div class="service-text">
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Código
<br />
</span>
<span style="font-size: 14px;">
<? echo $row["CodCurso"] ?> 
</span>
<br />
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Tipo:
<br />
</span>
<span class="pandin-1" >
<?php echo $strTipo ?>
</span>
<p></p>
<span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
Duración:
<br />
</span>
<span class="pandin-1" >
<?php echo $row["Duracion"] ?> Horas
</span>
<br />
</div>

<br />
<div class="contenidocapacitacion">

 <a href="<?php echo $row["UrlConferencia"] ?>" target="_blank" style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">
    <button style="background-color:#2E9AFE;">Realizar Registro</button>
    </a> 

 </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</table>
</div>

</section>

<?php
include("_parteFin_New2019.php");
?>
<?php

$result->closeCursor();
$link=null;
//--
?>
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: @Jheyman Mejia, lo que he intentado es modificar el tamaño del <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-4"> , pero no he tenido éxito.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices a lo mucho 1 o 2 propiedades del sistema de grillas de Bootstrap para evitar problemas. Si vas a utilizar más, hazlo en distintos div, no todo en uno.